# Stored Procedure for converting rows to columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I'm looking for an efficient way of how to convert rows to columns in SQL Server. I tried in Toad for Oracle, but now I want it in SQL Server.

This is my example:

```
CID   SENTENCE
1   Hello; Hi;
2   Why; What;
```

The result should be like

```
CID   SENTENCE

1   Hello
1   Hi
2   Why
2   What
```

Would you please help me with it?

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to rethink your database design. It's *almost never a good idea* to store data in a delimited string in any relational database.
If it's impossible to change your database design, you need to use some `UDF` to split strings.
There are many different approaches to split strings in sql server, read [this article](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings) on the differences between the common ways.

You can probably change your chosen split string function to take the `cid` as well as the `sentence` as a variable and have it return the data exactly as your desired output for each row in your table.
Then all you have to do is a select from your table with an inner join with the `udf` on the cid.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
  declare @var table (CID int,   SENTENCE  varchar(50))
    insert into @var(CID,SENTENCE) values
    (1,'Hello; Hi;'),
    (2,'Why; What;')

    select cid,t.c.value('.','varchar(50)') as val 
from (select cid,x=cast('<t>'+ replace(stuff(sentence,len(sentence),1,''),';','</t><t>')+'</t>'  as xml) 
 from @var) a cross apply x.nodes('/t')  t(c)
```